# Glassfish server 3.1.2 only works once

Tags: netbeans, windows-7, glassfish

I am having trouble with Glassfish 3.1.2 on Netbeans 7.3. Every time I click on the "Stop server" button on Netbeans, I have to create a new domain because it does not start when I run the application.

I have been looking around, but until now, I have not found any possible solution for this. Does anyone know what may be happening with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the NetBeans configuration file before opening NetBeans. On Windows 8 this file is in C:\Users\Group\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8. Just remove the subdirectory named 8 (or 7.3), then NetBeans will start like freshed installed and GlassFish runs like brand new ... until you close NetBeans, then you repeat the process. This way is easier and faster than un-install and re-install the whole NetBeans.