# Can't start GlassFish 4.1 from Netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: netbeans-8, glassfish-4.1

I can't start GlassFish from NetBeans. In asadmin.bat server starts just fine with no errors. In NB it freezes on Starting GlassFish Server and nothing happens.

I tried to run as administrator, reinstall, couple of strange things and nothing helps.

Windows 8.1 NetBeans 8.0.2 GlassFish 4.1

Comment: Maybe the NB's configuration data is not been removed, try this = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806648/glassfish-server-3-1-2-only-works-once/23225084#23225084

Comment: I deleted these files, but it's still not working.

Comment: Has it ever worked? If your NB with GF has never worked, maybe you should try to download it again, try a previous version. Did you download them separated or are you using the Glass Fish that comes with NB?

Comment: A week ago I had NB 8.0 with GF 4.0 and it worked perfectly. And after installation it was fine. But I restarted IDE and it happend.

Comment: Well, it's possible that, thanks to you, now we all know that NB 8.0.2 is not working well with GlassFish 4.1.

Comment: But it's bundled with it.

And my friend with the same configuration doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Is it a "port" issue? Maybe other program is using the same ports GlassFish needs.

Comment: A checked it and every needed port is free. From console server starts immediately. Only through NB it doesn't. What is surprising starting from NB isn't in the logs.

Comment: You are not the only one = https://forums.netbeans.org/post-163034.html . You must do more research on your friend's computer : hardware differences, software installed (or not installed), or just knock him out and take his computer. You know, with Android, a simple blank space in a directory name prevent project to run, maybe that's your case, something so small that you miss it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works! Finally!

Jose Manuel Abarca Rodríguez thank you very much for your attention.

I installed jdk 1.8.0_45 (before _31), reinstalled NB and it started to work normally. I hope it will stay that way.

Comment: I finally figured out why it happens. When some projects stay deployed on GF and then server shuts down it won't start again. I need to start serwer from console and undeploy this project. Then everything works.

I don't know why some deployed projects do this.